# Создание библиотеки иконок. Экспорт иконок в проект

Tags: c#

Я хочу создать одно хранилище иконок в библиотеке для использования в разных проектах. Но после добавления иконок к ресурсам библиотеки и создания ссылки в проекте можно добавлять иконки только из ресурсов локального компьютера, т.е. Библиотека вообще не задействована, но необходимо обратное. Как я могу экспортировать иконки из библиотеки? Как создать связь с проектом?

Comment: Что такое "иконка"? PNG/SVG картинка? Или вам нужна нативная DLL с набором `.ico` картинок?

Comment: да, png изображение. Проблема заключается в том, что при создании ссылки на библиотеку, картинки из ресурсов библиотеки не отображаются в ресурсах проекта на этапе разработки. Как сделать так, чтобы они отображались? Иначе нет смысла от библиотеки.

Comment: Картинки в ресурсах библиотеки не могут быть в ресурсах основного проекта, потому что это разные сборки. Чтобы подтянуть ресурс из подключенной сборки, вам нужно явно указывать на нее ссылку ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/338546/12888024), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7384672/12888024)).

Comment: спасибо за ответ!